# Owl Carousels not showing only 1 item

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

So, I'm using two Owl Carousels on the same page to slide through some data. The problem is that it always shows 2 items instead of 1.

Code:

```
$('#owl_radio_1').owlCarousel({
        item:1,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:3000,
        autoplayHoverPause:false
    });

    $('#owl_radio_2').owlCarousel({
        item:1,
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplayTimeout:3000,
        autoplayHoverPause:false
    });
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="owl_radio_<?php echo $x; ?>" class="owl-carousel">
     <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>
            <h3><?php echo $item; ?></h3>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

`$x` is a value which is going up by every iteration. So in this case it ends at 2

Comment: Can you show us html code

Comment: @Goku updated the post

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
$('#owl_radio_1').owlCarousel({
    items:1 //mistake in letter 's'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling Owl Carousel twice - try changing

`$('#owl_radio_1').owlCarousel`

to

`$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel`

EDIT: make sure you have your callout wrapped `$(document).ready();` so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#owl_radio_1').owlCarousel({
    item:1,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:3000,
    autoplayHoverPause:false
 });
})
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not fix it

Comment: Do you have your carousel callout wrapped in a `$( document ).ready()` ?

Comment: Yes I do have that